# Hibernate: switch from core API to JPA API without rewriting mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Is it possible to use a hbm xml Hibernate configuration to build an EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager in a JPA 2.0-compliant manner? The documentation seems to indicate this isn't possible:

> "The previous tutorials used the Hibernate-specific hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file. JPA, however, defines a different bootstrap process that uses its own configuration file named persistence.xml."
>   —[Chapter 4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html/ch04.html)

My hbm xml configuration is many thousands of lines long and works; I'd rather not have to rewrite by hand as orm.xml and persistence.xml. I also don't have write access to the data model to add Hibernate or JPA annotations. For my purposes I only need the JPA API, not the JPA configuration.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Existing mappings can be used by setting following property in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

Value is path to hibernate specific configuration. It is also possible to partially override hibernate style mappings with JPA mappings. Additional instructions can be found from documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html_single#d0e708