# Hibernate specific configuration in JPA XML mapping file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm using JPA with Hibernate. For the entities defined in my app, I use annotations, but some of the entities come as third-party code without any mappings. Therefore I have to map them via XML (at least I think I have to):

```
<entity-mappings ...>
    <access>FIELD</access>

    <mapped-superclass class="com.acme.common.model.Request">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id"/>
        </attributes>
    </mapped-superclass>
</entity-mappings>
```

Since this is JPA mapping, it works great except for one case where I have to use a Hibernate specific custom type to map PostgreSQL's `uuid` type to `java.util.UUID`.

Using annotations, it's a piece of cake:

```
@Entity
public class Partner {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
    private UUID id = IdGenerator.generate();
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do the same via XML.

I considered using Hibernate's native XML mapping, but it seems like it doesn't support mapped superclasses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate: switch from core API to JPA API without rewriting mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305204/hibernate-switch-from-core-api-to-jpa-api-without-rewriting-mapping)

Comment: Don't seems to be a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA mappings only supports its native API. You would need to use the hbm file.

You will have to migrate to a hbm mapping file with the property like:

Check out here for more details: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic.html

Comment: Does it mean I can't get the best of both worlds with XML like with annotations? I mean, I can combine both JPA and Hibernate annotations. By switching to Hibernate XML, does it mean I'll have to give up JPA features like mapped super classes?

Comment: You can have the JPA features, but you would need to use only Hibernate mappings. I never heard about a feature that allow a hbm file to import a orm (jpa only) file.